# WebAPI: Why do these methods match the routing template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I just re-read the [Routing in ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) document, and unless I'm missing something, by default WebAPI should only match methods that start with the HTTP verb. So why do I get this error when doing a POST against `/api/mymodels`:

```
ExceptionMessage, Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
Post on type MyApp.Controllers.MyModelController
MaterializerFactory on type Pyro.Controllers.MyModelsController
MaterializerFactory on type Pyro.Controllers.MyModelsController
QueryableFactory on type Pyro.Controllers.MyModelsController
```

Only the first one should match. Here are the routes from my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Children",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{childroute}/{childid}",
    defaults: new { childid = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here are the signatures for the erroneously matching methods:

```
public override JSONAPI.Core.IMaterializer MaterializerFactory() {}

public override TM MaterializerFactory<TM>() {}

public override IQueryable<T> QueryableFactory(Core.IMaterializer materializer = null) {}
```

The only possibly unusual thing about those is that they are inherited from an intermediate subclass of `ApiController` that I created…though I can't see how that would matter.

None of my methods are decorated with any WebAPI attributes (e.g. `AcceptVerbs`, `HttpPost`, etc.). If I decorate one of the above with `[NonAction]` it disappears from the list…but I don't know why it's even trying to match methods with those names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grrrr…okay, then I re-read the [Routing and Action Selection in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection), and buried in there is this gem:

> HTTP Methods. The framework only chooses actions that match the HTTP method of the request, determined as follows:
>
> - You can specify the HTTP method with an attribute: AcceptVerbs, HttpDelete, HttpGet, HttpHead, HttpOptions, HttpPatch, HttpPost, or HttpPut.
> - Otherwise, if the name of the controller method starts with "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Head", "Options", or "Patch", then by convention the action supports that HTTP method.
> - **If none of the above, the method supports POST.**

[image: head...explodes]

Okay, so this doesn't really stop you from decomposing your code into methods, you just can't make any of them `public`, or you have to put `[NonAction]` on them. Still, I wish that was far more obvious than a bullet buried in the "advanced topics" document.

Comment: Found this very helpful, wish this was more explicit or at least the behavior was configurable.